# How to send a response back to AJAX and continue php?

Tags: php, multithreading

So I'm trying to send an AJAX request to my PHP, where it makes a .jpg out of a .pdf file. This is all working fine, but I want to unlink the files from my server the moment they're shown on the site.

I've tried `flush()` and `ignore_user_abort(true);` but to no success.

**thumbnail.php**

```php
$pdfThumb->writeImage("../files/" . $fp);
ob_start();

//THIS SHOULD BE SENT TO AJAX
echo $fp;
ob_flush();
flush();

//THIS SHOULD BE DONE AFTER AJAX RECEIVES THE ECHO
unlink("../files/" . $fp);
```

**ajax**

```js
success: function(data){
  $("#fileHolder").attr("src", "files/" + data);
}
```

Maybe it'd also be possible to include a sleep() function right before the unlink to make 100% sure AJAX sets the image in HTML to the proper file?

Comment: Why not to generate the image right to the output? Why file is needed?

Comment: I can't set the image source via PHP, and I want to change the source without refreshing the page. So I'll need to use AJAX to send a request and receive a response.

Comment: you can use JavaScript to change the source and/or reload the image

Comment: Yes, but PHP is needed to convert the image from PDF to JPG. I can't change the source without converting it first, thus the reason I need the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of image, pass a reference to a "php" script.

```
<img src="..../getimage.php?file=myfile">
```

2. Write the script `getimage.php` which will pass the image to the browser and delete the file. Something like this

```
<?php
  // Disable caching
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");  // HTTP/1.1
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
  header("Pragma: no-cache");                          // HTTP/1.0

  // Safety check
  if (!isset($_GET['file']) || !preg_match('#^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$#', $_GET['file'])) die('Error');
  
  $file_name = 'files/' . $_GET['file'] . '.jpg';

  if (!file_exists($file_name) die('No file');

  // Set the content-type
  header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

  // pass the file to the browser
  readfile($file_name);

  // delete the file
  unlink ($file_name);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be extremely insecure? Assuming someone would remove the link inside the image, someone could upload unlimited amounts of PDFs to my server without having the script unlink my file.

Comment: Check and kill outdated files before running the script.